# Prevent tkinter window from minimizing but able to maximise and close window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, minimize

I want to prevent my tkinter window from minimizing but able to maximise and close the window.

Something like this

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: [If you intrested in windows styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603075/tkinter-customization-on-high-level/69605702#69605702)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your platform is Windows (looks like it is based on the image), you can call Windows functions via `pywin32` module to achieve the goal:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import win32con

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('MinimizeTest')
root.geometry('300x200')

def disable_minbox():
    # get window handle
    win_id = root.winfo_id()
    hwnd = win32gui.GetParent(win_id) 
    # get the current window style of root window
    style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE)
    # mask out minimize button
    style &= ~win32con.WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    # update the window style of root window
    win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE, style)

# need to do it when root window is displayed
root.after(1, disable_minbox)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you need to install `pywin32` using `pip`:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!  Do you mind if you briefly explain the code? Thanks.
EDIT: like what does the win32con.GWL_STYLE do

Comment: @CDN Update answer with explanation on each step.

Comment: @CDN Detail information on [`SetWindowLong()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) and [window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles).