# How to remove tkinter title bar without overrideredirect()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, titlebar

I am trying to make a custom title bar in tkinter, but when I remove it, the program disappears from the taskbar, task manager and so on. How could I fix this.

Comment: There is no way to remote the title bar without using `overrideredirect`.

Comment: As @BryanOakley said, there is no way to do this in tkinter, but you could of course use [os level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69605702/13629335) calls as tkinter does it for you under the hood.